# Retrieve data of a specific user from a Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve `data` from `Firebase Realtime Database`. It's working. My question is how to set text from `userDatabase`. The result will be `null` and I think it does not read the `database` while using `userID`.

```
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    String userid = user.getUid();

    txvEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txvEmail);
    txvEmail.setText("Welcome "+user.getEmail());

    txvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txvName);
    txvAdd =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txvAdd);

    userDatabase = new UserDatabase();

    reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Member").child(userid);
    reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            txvName.setText(" "+userDatabase.getFirstName()+" "+userDatabase.getLastName());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you must define your model class to values of snapshots

```
txvEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txvEmail);
txvEmail.setText("Welcome "+user.getEmail());

txvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txvName);
txvAdd =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txvAdd);

userDatabase = new UserDatabase();

reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Member").child(userid);
reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //new code
        for(DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            //you must define your class model to the value of snapshots
            userDatabase user = snap.getValue(userDatabase.Class);
             txvName.setText(" "+user.getFirstName()+" "+user.getLastName());
       }


    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much i never ever expected sombody reply so faster. And the answer help a lot thank you very much

Comment: Well you can accept my answer and raise if you want so